# Prolog | find the path from root to leaf with the maximal sum of node value

Tags: prolog

I need to create a prolog relation that receives a tree, sums the values in each nodes and finds the path with the maximal sum.

I've tried this method of a max sub tree:

```
max_sub_tree(Tree,T,N):-
    sol_tree_noroot(Tree,T1,N1),
    sol_tree_withroot(Tree,T2,N2),!,
    max_set(T1,N1,T2,N2,T,N).

max_set(T1, N1, T2, N2, T, N) :-
    (N1>N2,T=T1,N=N1;
     N2>N1,T=T2,N=N2;
    N2=:=N1,N=N1,(T=T1;T=T2)).    

sol_tree_noroot(nil,nil,0).
sol_tree_noroot(t(L,_,R),T,N):-
      max_sub_tree(L,T1,N1),max_sub_tree(R,T2,N2),!,
      max_set(T1, N1, T2, N2, T, N).

sol_tree_withroot(nil,nil,0).
sol_tree_withroot(t(L,X,R),t(L1,X,R1),N3):-
     sol_tree_withroot(L,T1,N1),sol_tree_withroot(R,T2,N2),
     max_set2(T1,N1,T2,N2,L1,R1,N),
     N3 is N+X.

max_set2(T1,N1,T2,N2,L,R,N):-
    (N1>0,N2>0,N is N1+N2,L=T1,R=T2;
     N1>=0,N2<0,N is N1 ,R=nil,L=T1;
     N1<0,N2>=0,N is N2 ,L=nil,R=T2;
     N1<0,N2<0,N1<N2,N is N2 ,L=nil,R=T2;
     N1<0,N2<0,N1>N2,N is N1 ,L=T1,R=nil;
     N1>0,N2=0,N is N1,(L=T1,R=nil;L=T1,R=T2);
     N1=0,N2>0,N is N2,(R=T2,L=nil;L=T1,R=T2);
     N1=0,N2=0,N is N1,(L=T1,R=nil;R=T2,L=T1;L=T1,R=T2)).
```

When I use the query

```
max_sub_tree(t(t(t(nil,2,nil),1,t(t(nil,40,nil),-30,nil)),-100,t(nil,50,t(nil,60,nil))) ,T,N).
```

I get

```
N = 110,
T = t(nil, 50, t(nil, 60, nil))
```

But I want the output to look like this:

```
N = 10,
T =.. [t, -100, 50, 60]
```

What Am I missing? how do I include the root? do i need to start over?

Comment: You should describe your predicates and functions so that we do not have to guess.

Comment: How can your output be `t(-100, 50, 60)`, it doesn't unify with the tree structure? Do you want your output to be a list of nodes: `T =.. [t, -100, 50, 60]`?

Comment: yes, @PaulBrown, exactly, I will fix the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Subtree Sums

This looks complicated, might I suggest we start from how to generate the sums of the subtrees that terminate in leaf nodes:

```
tree_sum(t(nil, N, nil), N). % leaf
tree_sum(t(T, N, nil), X) :- % only left branch
    tree_sum(T, M), X is N + M.
tree_sum(t(nil, N, T), X) :- % only right branch
    tree_sum(T, M), X is N + M.
tree_sum(t(T1, N, T2), X) :- % branches
    ( tree_sum(T1, M), X is N + M
    ; tree_sum(T2, M), X is N + M
    ).
```

That disjunction is where we need to focus to find the maximum tree sum, let's add that into our code next. There's no change to the first three rules

```
max_tree_sum(t(nil, N, nil), N). % leaf
max_tree_sum(t(T, N, nil), X) :- % only left branch
    max_tree_sum(T, M), X is N + M.
max_tree_sum(t(nil, N, T), X) :- % only right branch
    max_tree_sum(T, M), X is N + M.
max_tree_sum(t(T1, N, T2), X) :-
    max_tree_sum(T1, M1), X1 is N + M1,
    max_tree_sum(T2, M2), X2 is N + M12,
    X is max(X1, X2).
```

## A solution

Ok, so our code is finding the maximum solution, now we need it to track the path, building the list. We add in the final argument for this and an extra sub-predicate to do the comparison of branches for us:

```
max_tree_sum(t(nil, N, nil), N, [N]). % leaf
max_tree_sum(t(T, N, nil), X, [N|MT]) :- % left branch only
    max_tree_sum(T, M, MT), X is N + M.
max_tree_sum(t(nil, N, T), X, [N|MT]) :- % right branch only
    max_tree_sum(T, M, MT), X is N + M.
max_tree_sum(t(T1, N, T2), X, [N|T]) :- % branches
    max_tree_sum(T1, M1, MT1),
    max_tree_sum(T2, M2, MT2),
    max_subtree(M1, M2, MT1, MT2, M, T), X is M + N.

max_subtree(N1, N2, T1, _, N1, T1) :-
    N1 >= N2.
max_subtree(N1, N2, _, T2, N2, T2) :-
    N1 =< N2.
```

#### As Requested with `T =.. [t|Nodes]`

Now if you want the list converted to a predicate, put an extra predicate call to this:

```
max_subtree_sum(Tree, Sum, Pred) :-
    max_tree_sum(Tree, Sum, Path),
    Pred =.. [t|L].

?- max_subtree_sum(ExampleTree, 10, t(-100, 50, 60)).
```

But now `t(-100, 50, 60)` is not a tree.

Comment: Thanks! much appreciated.

Comment: One last question...can you give me an example of a  query for this that will work? one that gives the tree I gave in the example? that gives the path and the N?
thanks.
Again, your solution and explanation is beyond helpful.

Comment: I used your `max_sub_tree/3` query example. I named each predicate differently so you can easily try them all, but `max_subtree_sum(YourEgTree, T, N)` where YourEgTree is the one in your question will give you the desired output. `max_tree_sum/3` is the wiser one to use though.

Comment: one more question: If i want to compare all node values by their absolute value (I.E the above tree will return the path [-100,1,2] and N=97 because (-100+1+2) is -97, of which absolute value is 97, which is the maximum in this tree. do I just need to add  the function abs everywhere?

Comment: I've traced the way and it seems your method skips even checking the path from -100 to 1 to 2.